# Upgrade tesseract for iOS

Tags: ios, tesseract

I installed tesseract for my iOS app using the ObjC wrapper from ldiqual (https://github.com/ldiqual/tesseract-ios). I believe it is based on version 3.01 of tesseract, but I'd like to update so that I can run 3.02. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Have you found a way to succeed? I'm trying the same for MacOSX...

Comment: No, I haven't found an answer yet.